# Spring boot 2.1.4 ControllerAdvice not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I can't get this exception handling work. I look similar questions/answers but none of them worked. I have this class with `@ControllerAdvice` to handle application level error handling. This is not a REST application. It's Spring boot & Thymeleaf

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(LoginFailureException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleLoginFailureException(LoginFailureException exception) {
        log.info("Handle LoginFailureException");
        return getModelAndView(exception.getMessage(), "user/login");
    }

    // other exception handling methods

    private ModelAndView getModelAndView(String message, String viewName) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        FlashMessage flashMessage = new FlashMessage();
        flashMessage.setType("danger");
        flashMessage.setMessage(message);
        mav.getModel().put("flashMessage", flashMessage);
        mav.setViewName(viewName);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extended class, I have this

```
.failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
```

and `LoginFailureHandler` class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public LoginFailureHandler(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        throw new LoginFailureException(
                messageSource.getMessage("email.password.not.match", null, Locale.getDefault()));
    }
}
```

and when I try to login with a non valid username, my app crashes and throws this exception and never reach to ExceptionHandler method.

```
com.company.application.controller.exception.LoginFailureException: Email or Username is not valid
    at com.company.application.security.LoginFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(LoginFailureHandler.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: I wonder what this `getModelAndView()` function is doing.

Comment: @NavjotSingh That part is not reached but I added that part in my question in case you want to see it.

Answer (score 3):

`@ControllerAdvice` will only be hit when exceptions are thrown from `@Controller`, not `@Component`.

Since you are 'decorating' your login page with the danger/flash message, you might have to forward the `request` onto a new 'page' (e.g. `user/loginerror`) instead?

Comment: in my application an exception thrown in a Component trigger ControllerAdvice normally. What version are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main spring boot app to turn off auto config of Error Mvc 
 Configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not helping. Before when I click on "Login" button, I was redirected to the login page and see exception in the console, but with this in place, I get "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error" and stack trace in the frontend.

Comment: onAuthenticationFailure is a spring defined method in AuthenticationFailureHandler  and you throw the exception in this method but only exceptions thrown from a controller method impl reaches ControllerAdvice

Comment: Ok, then using AuthenticationFailureHandler will not help me here. I have to use something like `.failureUrl("/user-login?error=true")` for login and use exception handling for the rest of the application.